# Creating properties in literal object

Tags: javascript

```
var o, d;

o = { get foo() { return 17; } };
d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(o, "foo");
// d is { configurable: true, enumerable: true, get: /*the getter function*/, set:     undefined }
```

What does that `get` within the object do? Is that a method or property or something else?
How does it work or how it set property or method to object? Will i fall into trouble if i simply ignore the use of `get` and `set`?Are there more advantages in using `get` and `set` than simply defining property without there use.What are those advantages if any.Also what will the `.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` method returns? If it returns object, can I simply do `returnedobj.configurable` to access the configurable property-value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get` defines a *property accessor* function. When the value of the `foo` property on `o` is retrieved, that function is called even though it doesn't look like a function call in the code, e.g.:

```
var a = o.foo; // Note that `foo` doesn't have () after it, it's not a function call
```

In this case, it always returns 17, but it could do something else instead. For instance, consider a circle:

```
var circle = {
    radius: 7,
    get circumference() { return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius; },
    get area()          { return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius; }
};
console.log(circle.circumference); // 43.982297150257104 
console.log(circle.area);          // 153.93804002589985 
circle.radius = 4;
console.log(circle.circumference); // 25.132741228718345
console.log(circle.area);          // 50.26548245743669
```

As you can see, when we access the two properties we defined with accessors, the functions assigned to them get called, even though the property access doesn't look like a function call.

You can also have functions that get called when the property is *set*. Unsurprisingly, you do that using `set` rather than `get`. :-)

You can read more about this in the [object initializers](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5) part of the specification, and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get#Example:_Defining_a_getter_with_the_get_operator).

The `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` call returns an object that describes the property you asked for (in this case, `foo`). You can read more about it [in the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.3) and [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) as well.

Quoting from MDN:

> A property descriptor is a record *(TJC: e.g., object)* with some of the following attributes:
>
> `value`
>
> The value associated with the property (data descriptors only).
>
> `writable`
>
> `true` if and only if the value associated with the property may be changed (data descriptors only).
>
> `get`
>
> A function which serves as a getter for the property, or `undefined` if there is no getter (accessor descriptors only).
>
> `set`
>
> A function which serves as a setter for the property, or `undefined` if there is no setter (accessor descriptors only).
>
> `configurable`
>
> `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
>
> `enumerable`
>
> `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.

Answer (score 2):

`get` is part of the ECMAScript 5 syntax for defining property getters and setters.

Using object literal syntax, it's defined like this:

```
var obj = {
    __other_property__: null,
    get foo() { return "bar"; },
    set foo(v) { this.__other_property__ = v }
};
```

This lets you invoke the body of the getter function when doing  a get on the property.

```
obj.foo = "oof";
console.log(obj.foo); // "bar"
console.log(obj.__other_property__); // "oof"
```

---

The above uses `foo` to set a different property `__other_property__`. This could be a local variable or something else, and the functions can obviously  do far more complex operations than I'm showing here.

Comment: @Maizere: Yes, it returns an object with accessible properties. I figured you would find that out once you gave it a try.

Comment: i was afraid to try ,anyway thank u again.Also can u help me what "set" does? will the function get called when we set value

Comment: why haven't u use "()" in foo for invoking?

Comment: @Maizere: Don't be afraid... just jump right it and try things! ;-) Yes, with the setter you define a parameter, which is used to set the value. So these getter/setter properties allow more than just simple assignment and retrieval without having to use `()` on a function.

Comment: @Maizere: Because it isn't needed. Do some experimentation. I'll update my example object with the setter.